# Simple e-mail message previewer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop an utility which one helps to training Spamassassin. I fill a listview with subject, sender, etc at top and got two pre/view panes at the bottom, one textbox and one mail viewer. I'll mark the messages spam or ham if they are. So I have to see them first.

I can easily display the message source in textbox. However I couldn't success at displaying rich mail message. I tried webbrowser control, it displayed a few messages very well and not displayed -displayed as message source- most.

I totally don't know how to display mail messages. Is there any special component/control? Can I use Win7's built-in preview thingy? Or can I use Explorer's preview mechanism on my own utility? Sorry but at the moment I can't add any code because the question is not related any line of code, yet.

Comment: can you give us an example of an email that is not working?

Comment: Any .eml file like this: http://pastebin.com/bJ1WHKyP

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your email has embedded attachments that are hard to show. You can write some code to solve this but it is time expensive and it may not work as good as you like.

I had some problems with something similar some years ago. I used something like this at that point http://forums.asp.net/t/1350519.aspx

Update: Outlook needs to be installed on the PC. Someting similar can be done with Outlook Express you just need to find the COM dll.

Comment: Here is another solution; with the help of a component: http://www.example-code.com/delphi/parse-eml.asp

Answer (score 0):

I used **AE.Net.Mail** from https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail and did a few tests, worked very well!

Revisited code:

```
            string htmlBody = "", textBody = "";

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.Load(cellBody.Value.ToString(), false); // cellBody.Value.ToString() is raw message

            if (msg.Body != null)
            {
                switch (msg.ContentType)
                {
                    case "text/plain":
                        textBody = msg.Body;
                        break;
                    case "text/html":
                        htmlBody = msg.Body;
                        break;
                }
            }


            if(msg.AlternateViews.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Attachment alternateView in msg.AlternateViews)
                {

                    switch (alternateView.ContentType)
                    {
                        case "text/plain":
                            textBody = alternateView.Body;
                            break;
                        case "text/html":
                            htmlBody = alternateView.Body;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(msg.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Attachment attachment in msg.Attachments)
                {

                    switch (attachment.ContentType)
                    {
                        case "text/plain":
                            textBody = attachment.Body;
                            break;
                        case "text/html":
                            htmlBody = attachment.Body;
                            break;
                        case "message/rfc822":
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            textBody = "<pre>" + textBody + "</pre>";

            if (htmlBody == "")
                webBrowser1.DocumentText = textBody;
            else
                webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlBody;


            textBox1.Text = cellBody.Value.ToString();
```